# Firebase linkwithcredential not working with Facebook

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm working with a piece of code that attempts to use Firebase to link a Facebook auth credential to the current user. The current user creates an account with email/password, and then the Facebook credential is linked to this account at a later point in time. This code was previously working as intended, but our team required updating multiple firestore dependencies which seems to have broken this code. I am not sure what the problem is.

I've tried checking the contents of the token and there does not seem to be any problem with it. The code always fails at the linkwithcredential function. The login with Facebook UI works perfectly otherwise. The linkwithcredential function always spits out the same error.

My code:

```dart
fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile'])
.then((result) async 
{
    print(" == Right Before result.status");
    switch(result.status)
    {
        case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        {
          FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
          print("AccessToken = ${myToken.token.toString()}");
          AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
          FirebaseUser us = await FirebaseAuth.instance.linkWithCredential(credential);
         }
         //... other cases & error handling
     }
```

Output:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source:5)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source:2)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleLinkWithEmailAndPassword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:272)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:122)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:219)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(26676):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
I/flutter (26676): PlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter_facebook_login:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  cloud_firestore: 0.10.1
  firebase_database: ^1.0.5
  firebase_auth: 0.8.1 #^0.6.6
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
  firebase_storage: ^1.0.4

  webview_flutter: ^0.3.0


  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  cached_network_image: ^0.8.0

  fluttertoast: ^3.0.4
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.3.1

  image_picker: ^0.6.0
  image_cropper: ^1.0.1

  auto_size_text: ^1.1.2
  flutter_range_slider: "^1.1.0"
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  flutter_image: ^1.0.0

  page_view_indicators: ^1.1.0
  path: any
  intl: ^0.15.8
  stripe_payment: 0.1.0
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3
  latlong: ^0.6.1

  firebase_messaging: 4.0.0+4

  flutter_launcher_icons: 0.7.2
  stripe: 1.3.1
```

Obligatory flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching online it seems like this was a problem with Firebase-Auth. Updating Firebase-Auth from 0.8.1 to 0.8.2 solved the problem.